# Why doesn't UINavigationController have a rootViewController property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am very curious. We really can't access it easily. I mean, I know it has, but not accessible.

Why?

Basically I want that rootViewController to be loaded before sending some events by accessing it's view. There is an postnotification that's set up on viewDidload.

Answer (score 18):

If you have more than one, then use:

```
UIViewController *root = navController.viewControllers[0];
```

where `navController` is you `UINavigationController`. This will work always.

Use `UINavigationController topViewController`. This works if there is only one controller.

Comment: @HugoDozois Like what? The OP states that there is no `rootViewController` method to get the root view controller in the nab controller. Using `topViewController` will give you the root view controller (if there is only one view controller).

Comment: topViewController will give the upper most controller. I want the bottommost.

Comment: That's what I did. It still doesn't explain why we do not have rootViewController. This will be the correct answer unless someone else have better

Comment: Because you don't need the rootViewController very often, whereas the topViewController you do. If you really want, you can create a category on UINavigationController with a `rootViewController` property that simply returns `self.viewControllers[0]`...